# Bootstrap dropdowns doesn't work

Tags: navbar, dropdown

So in this navbar i've 2 dropdowns. One is when you are looking at the site on mobile the other is a dropdown. but these don't work. I've looked 2 hours for a solution but nothing yet...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts\bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link href="css\bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="Styles\main.css rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <!--Aanmaken van een navigatiebar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Van Beeck Telecom</a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Webshop</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Contact</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Openingsuren</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Route</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contactforumlier</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
       </div>
         <div>
            Lorem Ipsum is slechts een proeftekst uit het drukkerij- en    zetterijwezen. Lorem Ipsum is de standaard proeftekst in deze bedrijfstak sinds de 16e eeuw, toen een onbekende drukker een zethaak met letters nam en ze door elkaar husselde om een font-catalogus te maken. Het heeft niet alleen vijf eeuwen overleefd maar is ook, vrijwel onveranderd, overgenomen in elektronische letterzetting. Het is in de jaren '60 populair geworden met de introductie van     Letraset vellen met Lorem Ipsum passage
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

make sure that you load the bootstrap.min.js...
add a line of code like this in the templates footer

```
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

make sure that the bootstrap.min.js file is in the js folder.

UPDATE

your code should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="Styles/main.css rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <!--Aanmaken van een navigatiebar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Van Beeck Telecom</a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Webshop</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Contact</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Openingsuren</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Route</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contactforumlier</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
       </div>
         <div>
            Lorem Ipsum is slechts een proeftekst uit het drukkerij- en    zetterijwezen. Lorem Ipsum is de standaard proeftekst in deze bedrijfstak sinds de 16e eeuw, toen een onbekende drukker een zethaak met letters nam en ze door elkaar husselde om een font-catalogus te maken. Het heeft niet alleen vijf eeuwen overleefd maar is ook, vrijwel onveranderd, overgenomen in elektronische letterzetting. Het is in de jaren '60 populair geworden met de introductie van     Letraset vellen met Lorem Ipsum passage
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: If this answer was helpful please accept it as correct! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="scripts\bootstrap.js"></script>
```

in your code you have wrong sign, type it like bottom here:

```
<script src="scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct (and it works in my computer) so I assume the problem is within the javascript files. To test if this is the case, replace the script and link tags with the following:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet">
```

Then, one by one, change the external CDN to your local file, discovering when the problem occurs.

Alternatively, in Google Chrome, you can right-click anywhere in the page and select Inspect. Then in the Developer Tools, select the tab Console. Check if it shows something like this:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

This indicates the script file is not being loaded.

Lastly, you might have the javascript execution disabled in your browser. You can find this in the settings.